# jssor scrolling-logo-thumbnail-slider.source.html

Tags: jquery, jssor

I did edit the following the jssor scrolling-logo-thumbnail-slider.source.html so when you click on the img it send you to an webpage i did use the following code

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank" img u="image" alt="facebook" src="../img/logo/facebook.jpg"/a>
```

But what is happening is that the image is resized to the original size can some one please tell me what is the correct code to use to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong html code, please use the following,

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img u="image" alt="facebook" src="../img/logo/facebook.jpg" /></a>
```

For backward compatibility of jssor slider old version, please use,

```
<a u="image" href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><img alt="facebook" src="../img/logo/facebook.jpg" /></a>
```

Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/define-slides-html-code.html